# Random module does not shuffle sounds loaded into a list

Tags: python

I am using the random module in python to pick a song with an absolute path very time i launch the script. I loaded the song variables into a list and shuffled it with random, but the songs never shuffle neither does the `random.choice` method work. The songs are played in the same order every time. How do i achieve my goal of randomly selecting any of the three sound files to play?

```
import random
import os

duration = 60
newSongLocation1 = "~/Desktop/work/auto_response/boot_sequence_offline.wav"
newSongLocation2 = "~/Desktop/work/auto_response/boot_sequence_online.wav"
newSongLocation3 = "~/Desktop/work/auto_response/welcome_to_the_future.wav"

playSong1 = os.system('aplay -q -d {} {}'.format(duration, newSongLocation1))
playSong2 = os.system('aplay -q -d {} {}'.format(duration, newSongLocation2))
playSong3 = os.system('aplay -q -d {} {}'.format(duration, newSongLocation3))


songArray = [playSong1,
    playSong2,
    playSong3]

random.shuffle (songArray,random)
random.choice(songArray, random)
```

Comment: Why are you randomly shuffling the list and then randomly picking an element from said randomly shuffled list?

Comment: You make the call to `os.system(...)` before you use `random`; so the songs will always be played in the order you defined in your file.

Comment: put them in the list, shuffle it, play them in order of list using a loop. remove the play commands before it.

Answer (score 2):

The `os.system()` calls do the actual work of running those commands, and block until they are done. You should generate a randomly ordered list of the songs that you want to play and then loop over them.

```py
import random
import os

duration = 60
songLocations = [
    "~/Desktop/work/auto_response/boot_sequence_offline.wav",
    "~/Desktop/work/auto_response/boot_sequence_online.wav",
    "~/Desktop/work/auto_response/welcome_to_the_future.wav"
]
random.shuffle(songLocations)
for song in songLocations:
    os.system('aplay -q -d {} {}'.format(duration, song))
```

**EDIT** To play one random song each run of the script, change the last three lines to

```py
song = random.choose(songLocations)
os.system('aplay -q -d {} {}'.format(duration, song))
```

Comment: What if i want to randomly play only one song from the list every time i launch the script, how do i implement that?

Comment: Edited to add simple answer, but Ralf's `[:num_songs]` technique lets you play more than one if you want to, the better answer unless your list of files is huge.

Answer (score 2):

You need to shuffle before you play the songs with `os.system()`.

Also, if you only want to play a specific number of songs and not the whole list, then you could use `random.shuffle()` on the list then then slice the list to the desired size.

Additionally, I added some suggestions to make the script more robust, reduce the repetitions of the same text or code to the minimum, and added print statements to inspect the state of the variables during execution.

Maybe like this:

```
import os
import random

num_songs = 2
base_cmd = 'aplay -q -d {} {}'
duration = 60
base_path = os.path.join('~', 'Desktop', 'work', 'auto_response')
filename_list = [
    'boot_sequence_offline.wav',
    'boot_sequence_online.wav',
    'welcome_to_the_future.wav',
]

print('Before shuffle:', filename_list)
random.shuffle(filename_list)
print('After shuffle:', filename_list)

print()
print('Songs played:')
for filename in filename_list[:num_songs]:
    cmd = base_cmd.format(duration, os.path.join(base_path, filename))
    print('   cmd:', cmd)
    os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: I liked the `print(song_list)`. Thanks a bunch it worked like a breeze.

Comment: @AllenJakpa I read your comment on the other answer and edited my answer to include a few additional things.